# Change background-img color with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have the **css** below on my page. I want my visitors to be able to change the color of that image by typing in a #colorcode in a text field. Is something like this even possible?

```
.button{
    background-image:url(../pattern/_img/button.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    width:53px;
    height:53px;
    float:left;
    margin:16px;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by changing the color of the image?

Comment: you want to change the background color? or background image itself?

Comment: You have a background "IMAGE". JQuery and photoshp are two different things. As far as i know,  You can't change the color of an image using jq. You can however change the background image itself.
or maybe use some sort of transparent image

Comment: Well, what I meant was this (http://users7.jabry.com/overlord/mug.html) but for background-img

Comment: @user3290485: Link that you shared is html5 canvas which is used to draw graphics. You cannot change background image color using css.

Comment: well, i beleive that image is an SVG. not  the ones like jpg or png

Comment: This is possible if you are using the Transparent PNG format of image.

Comment: If you want to achieve something as simple as under the link shown – then you could use a PNG image with white on the “outside”, and an (alpha-)transparent area for the shape of the mug … and then simply set a background-color, that would achieve roughly the same. If you want something more complex – well then you’ll have to properly explain what exactly you want first.

Comment: @CBroe he is using PNG format but he need to make sure that PNG have a transparent background.

Comment: That’s what I said, isn’t it?

Comment: you can use a jquery plugin called `jPicker`. It will be a better approach to give the use option to pick the color instead of typing the color `hex value`. Plugin is available here. http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to change your image. Take a PNG image with white outside and empty (but let your gradient) inside like this for you:
[image: mug]

Then set a div behind the image. It's the background-color of that div which will change. In your js just set:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('color').value;
```

This not use canvas but this is working with few code.

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82Anz/).

Sorry for the english and hope it will help you!

Ah, and the image above is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3tfM.jpg).